# Erase a cell by pressing a button in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in Excel. I'd like to press a button to cancel the value of the cell at the left of the button itself.

So the user experience should be the following:

[image]

When the user presses "button1", the cell at its left became 0. The same for "button2" and "button3"
How can I do?
By using a Macro?

Comment: It's called the [Del] or [Delete] key.

Comment: Yes, you'll use a macro that does something like `Cells(1,1).ClearContents`.  But @Jeeped makes a great point - what're you trying to do with this button? I'm hoping this is a way simplified question and you're going to use it for something more nuanced than a user being able to just `Delete`.  Potentially an [XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Hi Bruce and hi Jeeped. I have simply to remove a debit from a list and I want to do it by pressing a button, just for didactic aims!
The question is: have I do to do 3 macros for deleting 3 cells? It's not very smart: could I make a reference in the code of the Macro to say: "look at pressed button and delete the value at its left".
So just one macro does all the work for every button

Comment: Then your question actually becomes *'How can I have one macro for three buttons (each performing a slightly different task) ?'* Thank you. That's a duplicate question and I can now go find an answer to mark this as a duplicate with.

Comment: No Jeeped, you are wrong: my question is that above and therefore is not a duplicate of that you wrote. By the way, if you answer to the question you wrote, you give a plusvalue to my question. But they are different.

Comment: What @Jeeped is saying is you want a macro that performs *slightly* differentl, depending on where it's run from.  The macro will delete cells, the slight difference is *which* cell to delete.  Actually, you could even use a single macro that just uses something like `ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).ClearContents`.

Comment: You need to trigger the macro using Hyperlink, in your macro code, follow @BruceWayne 's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign this macro to any and all buttons, and it'll delete the info. in the cell directly to the left.

```
Sub test()
    Dim btnRow&, btnCol&
    btnRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    btnCol = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column
    Cells(btnRow, btnCol).Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Or, thanks to @Rory, this can be:

```
Sub test()
    Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.offset(0,-1).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Note: Make sure your shapes are well placed, as this uses wherever the **top left** of the shape is to determine the row/column.  This macro reduces the need to run three different ones, depending on where, and minimizes any If/Then type statements as it uses the `Caller` to determine which shape, which determines where it is.

Comment: Why not just `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents`?

Comment: @Rory - I don't know why not! That looks great, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

If your using command button

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()
    Range("A1") = 0
End Sub
```

or assign to worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then _
      Range("A1") = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: With `Button1_Click`, is there a way to determine which cell the Button is in? If so, you could replace the `Range` with something like `Cells(Button1.Row,Button1.Column).Offset(0,-1).ClearContents` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

May this help...

```
'Add three buttons on the sheet
'And imaging that you want to delete B4 B5 B6
'You can discover which button is, by double cliking on the desing mode
'on your excel
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'This is the button on the cell C4
    Range("B4").ClearContents
    'Here B4 is the range of the cell you want to delete...
    'This could be acomplish just pressing the button DELETE
    'Same by the two other buttons... just adding 1 to the number
    'B4...B5...B6
    'With this you only can delete de contents of the cell...
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'This is the button on the cell C5
    Range("B5").ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 'This is the button on the cell C6
    Range("B6").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink method is what I've done before. Like it, because it look like it can click.

[image]

Add below code on the Worksheet module, when a hyperlink clicked, it will trigger the sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If LCase(Target.Range.Text) Like "delete*" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use below code to generate as much as hyperlink you want.

```
Sheets(XXX).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                        "", TextToDisplay:="Delete"
```